# Column in Date type Value Create new Column

Tags: date, powerbi, dax

My Column in this type of Data
[Click for Display Column value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVCYA.png)

this column is in only date 'DD/MM/YYYY' format date insert a new column otherwise null

that means value = Date(DD/MM/YYYY) then new Column in Date Otherwise  Null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new column and paste this DAX Code to extract only row values which has a date format using DATEVALUE function in a conditional expression: Here is the code:

```
IsDate = IFERROR(DATEVALUE([Expected Date]),BLANK())
```

[image: OnlyDateFormattedValuesShow on the screen]

Comment: Your Answer is Perfect